# Transform polar coordinates to rectangular

Tags: simplifying-expressions, coordinate-transformation

I am not satisfied, I'll be wrong?
I used this

```
Simplify[r*Cos[θ]^2 == 
Sqrt[2]*Sin[θ + π/4] /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
z -> ArcTan[y/x]}]
```

[image]

Comment: why would you expect the `z->` rule to do anything when there is no `z` in your expression?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this?

```
Simplify@TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
  r*Cos[θ]^2 == Sqrt[2]*Sin[θ + Pi/4], {r, θ} -> {x, y}]
```

(Note `Pi` is spelled, like all *Mathematica* keywords, with an initial capital.)

Comment: **(Note Pi is spelled, like all Mathematica keywords, with an initial capital.)**The latter do not understand,
ah one more thing, what would be the reverse order of Cartesian to polar

thank you very much for your attention

Comment: @juanmuñoz The reverse would be `TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar",...]`.  You can find other transformations in the documentation for `TransformedField`, which explains how the function works.

Comment: @juanmuñoz You wrote `pi` in your question.  It should be `Pi`, with an initial capital `P`.  Feyre has changed it to `π` for some unknown reason. (I would have thought it bad form to introduce fixes in someone else's question.)  -- All *Mathematica* function names and other keywords use capital letters (`Sin[]`, `Cos[]`, `E`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Just a rule  based way (I have voted for MichaelE2's answer which uses a built-in function):

```
eq = r Cos[t]^2 == Sqrt[2] Sin[t + Pi/4];
den = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
re = Simplify[
  TrigExpand[eq] /. {r -> den, Cos[t] -> x/den, Sin[t] -> y/den}];
Legended[Show[Plot[y /. Solve[re, y][[1]], {x, -3, 3}],
  PolarPlot[Sqrt[2] Sin[t + Pi/4]/Cos[t]^2, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/4}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True], 
 LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)-x", 
   "r= \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\)\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(\\\ \)\(Sin[t + \
π/4]\)\), SuperscriptBox[\(Cos[t]\), \(2\)]]\)"}]]
```

[image]

Note: `y /. Solve[re, y][[1]]` yields :`-x+x^2`